# Meaning of Mayuravarma

Tags: name, meaning

I was looking online in search of the meaning of the word - `Mayuravarma`. This is the name of the founder of Kadamba dynasty. `Mayura` means `Peacock` and `Varma` means `Armour`. So it means Armour of the Peacock. So my question is does it refer to `Lord Subrahmanya` or anything else? I also would like to know if it refers to any other God?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a stone inscription at Kargudari in the Hangal taluka, Mayuravarman was a son of the god Shiva and the Earth:

> Regarding Mayūravarman L., who heads the list, and who appears to have been **represented by tradition as tree-eyed and four-armed**, the Kargudari record asserts that he was a **son of the god Śiva and the Earth**, and that he came from the Himālayan regions, and, having brought from Ahicchatra eighteen Brāhmaṇs whom he established in the Kuntala country, thus acquired the government of the earth. He seems to be identical with the Mukaṇṇa-Kadamba,—."the three-eyed Kadamba,"—of another record, who is said to have brought twelve-thousand Brāhmaṇs, of thirty-two gotras, purified by performing the agnihotra-sacrifice, from the agrahāra of Ahich-chatra, and to have made, and established them in, the agrahāra of Sthāṇugūḍhapura, which is the modern Tālgund in the Shimogga District, Mysore. And his name in the form of Mayūravarman is very possibly nothing but a reminiscence of that of the veritable Mayūra-śarman, who established the early Kadamba power.

Source: [*The Kadambas of Hangal*, Bombay Gazetteer](https://gazetteers.maharashtra.gov.in/cultural.maharashtra.gov.in/english/gazetteer/Gazetteer%20of%20Bombay%20Presidency/home.html) also on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.280089/page/n619/mode/2up)

The same source, but under the heading *The Kadambas of Goa* suggests the identification of Mayuravarman with Trilocana-Kādamba:

> As we have seen above, the Kādāmbas of Hāngal derived their descent from the three-eyed and four-armed Mayūravarman, a son of the god Śiva and the Earth. **Whereas the Kādāmbas of Goa attributed their origin to the three-eyed and four-armed Jayanta, otherwise called Trilocana-Kādamba** or "the three-eyed Kadamba," who is said to have sprung from a drop of sweat that fell to earth near the roots of a kadamba-tree from the forehead of the god Śiva after his conquest of the demon Tripura.[1304]thee records of the Kādāmbas of Goa, hewever, do not give a long and questionable pedigree like that of their relations of Hāngal They present historical names only.

Comment: Yups. He bought shiivalli brahmins from ahischattra. Most of them now are followers of dwaita  but how did they got settled in udupi. From thirtahalli to udupi...